# Get full path name in layout.js (NextJS 13 and app directory)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I want to get the URL `/events/345/edit` in `layout.js`. I want to display "page name" on each `page.js`, but for me to do that I need to know where I am in `layout.js` so I can display it there.

```
   app
     - layout.js
     - events
       - [eventId]
         - edit
           - page.jsx
```

Answer (score 1):

Layouts do not have access to the route segments below itself. To access all route segments, you can use [useSelectedLayoutSegment](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-selected-layout-segment) or [useSelectedLayoutSegments](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-selected-layout-segments) in a Client Component.